# Storing User Input from Form into an Array - undefined is not a function (evaluating - error

Tags: javascript, arrays, html, forms

I believe i'm missing something simple. I think i have the code

```
var textarea = document.getElementById("printArray");
firstLastNameInput.value = textarea.join("\n");
```

in the wrong spot, also i think i could be using the wrong variable.

Is my onClick calling the wrong function? Not really sure what I am doing wrong.

```
   <!DOCTYPE html>
   <html lang="en">
<head> 
<title>assign 8</title>  
<meta charset="utf-8">

<style>
form {text-align:center;text-size:2em;}
</style>

<script>
var firstLastName = [];
var yearBirth = [];
var education = [];
var marital = [];

var firstLastNameInput = document.getElementById("firstLastName");
var yearBirthInput = document.getElementById("yearBirth");
var educationInput = document.getElementById("education");
var maritalInput = document.getElementById("marital");

function insert () {
    firstLastName.push( firstLastNameInput.value );
    yearBirth.push( yearBirthInput.value );
    education.push( educationInput.value );
    marital.push( maritalInput.value );

    clearAndShow();
}

function clearAndShow () {
    var textarea = document.getElementById("printArray");
firstLastNameInput.value = textarea.join("\n");

firstLastNameInput.value = "";
yearBirthInput.value = "";
educationInput.value = "";
maritalInput.value = ""; 
}
</script>

</head>
<body> 
<form>
<input type="text" id="firstLastName" value="First & Last Name">
    <br>
<input type="text" id="yearBirth" value="Year of Birth (ex: 1900)">
    <br>
<select id="education" size="3">
<option>Education:</option>
<option>__________</option>
<option>High School Diploma</option>
<option>College Degree</option>
<option>Graduate Degree</option>
</select>
<br>
<select id="marital" size="2">
<option>Marital Status:</option>
<option>__________</option>
<option>Yes</option>
<option>No</option>
</select>
<br>
<input type="submit" value="Submit" onClick="clearAndShow()">
</form>

<textarea id="printArray"></textarea>

</body>  
</html>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
var textarea = document.getElementById("printArray");
```

is the reference to `<textarea>` node. So it has not method `join()`

You should get the value of it first:

```
var textarea = document.getElementById("printArray").value;
```

It will be string and it has not method `join()` too. In JavaScript you can simply:

```
firstLastNameInput.value = textarea + '\n';
```